# Android Timer running too frequently

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a timer task, **checkHour** implemented in my code.  This task checks if the current hour is between a certain time and, depending on the time and if updates are on, turns on/off location updates.

Below is my timer task:

```
TimerTask checkHour = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i("TIMER :: ", "CHECKING HOUR...");
                    LocationServices.getCurrentHour();
                    //If updates are off and it is before 7:00 am or after 5:00 pm, stop updates
                    if (LocationServices.currentHour >= endTime && updatesOn) {
                        Log.i("TURNING UPDATES :: ", "OFF");
                        LocationServices.stopLocationUpdates();
                    }

                    //If updates are off and it is between 7:00 am and 5:00 pm, start updates
                    if ((LocationServices.currentHour >= startTime && LocationServices.currentHour < endTime) && !updatesOn) {
                        Log.i("TURNING UPDATES :: ", "ON");
                        LocationServices.startUpdates(context, null);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And I am implementing it like this in my onCreate method:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(checkHour, 1000, 600000);
```

From what I have read here(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), **schedule** should start the timer task after the delay (1000 ms for me) and then run the task after every period (600000 ms or 10 minutes for me).  However, it is running very inconsistently.  Here is a snippet of the log for checking the hour with the time they are running:

```
08-06 12:35:08.575  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:35:22.960  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:35:23.877  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:35:40.739  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:35:44.144  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:36:09.826  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:37:49.706  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:38:25.042  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:38:47.019  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:38:50.588  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:39:12.093  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:39:14.529  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
08-06 12:39:20.179  27652-27652/org.apsugis.pickupdetect I/TIMER ::﹕ CHECKING HOUR...
```

My question is why is my timer running every minute or so instead of every 10 minutes?

Comment: are you running this in an emulator or on a real device?

Comment: I am running this on a second generation Moto G.  Android version 5.0.2

Comment: probably caused by multiple instances of timer running together

Comment: There are few reasons to use `Timer` on Android, and this is not one of them.  The requirements you describe call for an [alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I did not think to use an alarm.